# His talent was allied with an insdustry .. - precise meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I would like to ask for help with the following sentence (from a short story by C.A. Smith):

> The authentic talent of Francis La Porte, fiction-writer, was allied
> with an industry no less than prodigious. Unfortunately, he was self-critical to an excessive degree.

I am not sure I got it right - especially the "allied with an industry" part.

My understand would be: His true, great talent was tied/linked/associated with an industry that was at least prodigious.
But the "industry" just does not make much sense to me, probably because it is used in a way I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of **industry** here is this:
[American Heritage Dictionary "industry"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=industry)

2. Energetic devotion to a task or an endeavor; diligence:
   *demonstrated great intelligence and industry as a prosecutor.*

The meaning of **prodigious** is this:
[American Heritage Dictionary "prodigious"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=prodigious)
2. Extraordinary; marvelous: a prodigious talent.

So, Francis La Porte had an authentic talent coupled with an extraordinary devotion to his work.

Comment: Thank you! Is that a common usage in current English?

Comment: It's less common than the other meaning of "industry", but it's not unusual.

Comment: Thank you. If I may one more thing, in order no to create a new question:  Though editors importuned him for stories and bought readily the few that he submitted, Francis could seldom outdistance the wolf by a full running jump.  // is the meaning of the last part literal? That he was rarely ahead with his work (I guess "the wolf" refers to the editors importuning him).

Comment: That's certainly figurative, not literal. The passage does seem to describe someone who had a  lot of unfinished work around him, so I suppose that's what it's referring to. It's not a standard metaphor that I recognize.